# Is there a way to declare a private object from another file?

Tags: java

Okay, I really cannot find a good way to put this into words. Is there a way to declare all things in a public class, but privately and in another file/class **without knowing what all the objects are**? Here's an example.

**SetOfThings.java**

```java
public class SetOfThings {
   // For the sake of the question, say these can change
   // from time to time
   public int someNumber = 1;
   public string someString = "Java is kinda challenging sometimes...";
   public Joystick example = new Joystick(someNumber);
}
```

**SomeOtherFile.java**

```java
public class SomeOtherFile {
   /** Some way to recreate all the public objects from 
    * SetOfThings with the same values, but private 
    * (perhaps final, too?) and without having to 
    * know what all the objects in SetOfThings are.
    */
}
```

I've already searched around, but as I said, I can't figure out how to word it without being overly specific. Currently, I'd have to edit each and every file to update the things I'm calling that are used separately.

Comment: Have you considered having `SomeOtherFile` contain a single `private SetOfThings setOfThings`? That would be the typical way to contain one data structure in another.

Comment: Being specific might improve your Question. Also, your use of the word "File" here is confusing, as that implies a [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is in your constructor of `SomeOtherFile.java`to add a private variable `SetOfThings things;` your code could look something like this

**SetOfThings.java**

```
    public class SetOfThings {
   // For the sake of the question, say these can change
   // from time to time
   public int someNumber = 1;
   public string someString = "Java is kinda challenging sometimes...";
   public Joystick example = new Joystick(someNumber);
}
```

**SomeOtherFile.java**

```
    public class SomeOtherFile {
           private SetOfThings setOfThings; //this is so you can access all the SetOfThings variables
           public SomeOtherFile(SetOfThings things){
                this.setOfThings=things //attribute things to the private variable
           }
    }
```

like this you have access to your `SetOfThings.java` in your `SomeOtherFile.java`.
If your values don't change you also have the option to simply declare a `SetOfThing` object in your `SomeOtherFile`

```
SetOfThing myObjectInOtherClass=new SetOfThing();
```

Comment: Also helpful to OP would be deep/shallow copying in case he doesnt want modifying one SetOfThing to modify another if they are both given same object.